# Refactor big switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, refactoring

I have the following switch statement:

```
switch (type) {
  case 1: // 1 BYTE 8-bit unsigned integer
    pointer = count > 4 ? offset : pointer;
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      value += dataView.getUint8(pointer + i);
    }
    tag.value = parseInt(value, 10);
    return tag;
  case 3: // 3 SHORT 16-bit unsigned integer
    pointer = count > 2 ? offset : pointer;
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      value += dataView.getUint16(pointer + 2 * i, littleEnd);
    }
    tag.value = parseInt(value, 10);
    return tag;
  case 4: // 4 LONG 32-bit unsigned integer
    pointer = count > 1 ? offset : pointer;
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      value += dataView.getUint32(pointer + 4 * i, littleEnd);
    }
    tag.value = parseInt(value, 10);
    return tag;
  case 5:
  ...
```

and so on.

The pattern is every time the same with some small variations. How can I refactor this? I want to refactor the pattern inside the case and I'm also trying to remove the whole switch block. Is that possible?

Comment: I think the switch statement is probably worth keeping.  I would start to refactor by pulling out the individual case blocks into their own functions.  That would make them easier to test and and debug.

Comment: The least common denominator seems to be

initialize pointer;
for(let i= 0; i < i count; i++)
{
    value += dataView.GetSomeValue(pointerLocation, littleEnd)
tag.value = parseInt(value, 10);
return tag;
}

so, think would set up a main function to do the the loop and pass in the pointer calculation  function as a parameter, and the dataView.getValue function as a parameter,  and incrementPointer function as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This probably belongs on the Code Review Stack Exchange.)

Without a bit of larger context it's difficult to provide a reasonable refactoring, or even determine if such a refactoring would be worth the effort and additional maintenance.

The nutshell is that you have a number of `type` that need to be handled. Rather than a switch, you could implement a command pattern where each type is either a small class, or a simple object. (Using a class makes it marginally easier to pass in an "execution context" that contains the variables not shown in the snippet.)

For the sake of brevity, here's a (**very**) rough outline.

---

You'd have a base type handler. This wraps up `dataView` looping and tag value setting. Since I don't know the context, I'm pretending there's a context you pass in. I include all variables that weren't shown in your snippet.

*(I didn't include `value`, which it looks like you should, but I didn't know the intent.)*

```
class BaseTypeHandler {
  constructor(ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx
  }

  getPointer  = () => throw new Error('Missing getPointer implementation')
  getViewData = () => throw new Error('Missing getViewData implementation')

  getValueFromDataView = () => {
    let value = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < this.ctx.count; i++) {
      value += this.getViewData(i, pointer)
    }

    return value
  }

  getTag = () => {
    const pointer = this.getPointer()
        , value   = this.getValueFromDataView()

    this.ctx.tag.value = parseInt(value, 10)
    return this.ctx.tag
  }
}
```

Each subclass implements the required unique functionality, here how to get the pointer, and how to get data from the `dataView`.

```
class Type1Handler extends BaseTypeHandler {
  getPointer = () => 
    this.ctx.count > 4 ? this.ctx.offset : this.ctx.pointer

  getViewData = (i, pointer) =>
    this.ctx.dataView.getUint8(pointer + i)
}

class Type3Handler extends BaseTypeHandler {
  getPointer = () => 
    this.ctx.count > 2 ? this.ctx.offset : this.ctx.pointer

  getViewData = (i, pointer) =>
    this.ctx.dataView.getUint16(pointer + 2 * i, littleEnd);
}
```

Then you wrap those up in an object of type handlers:

```
const typeHandlers = {
  1: Type1Handler,
  3: Type3Handler,
  4: Type4Handler
}

const handler = new typeHandlers(type)
    , tag = handler.getTag()
```

**TL;DR**

Unless you have a tremendous number of these, and you cannot use math to figure out the `getPointer` and `getViewData` implementations, you might want to stick with the `switch`.

Simple objects or immediate functions may be a significantly smaller implementation, although not necessarily easier to reason about. They also have the advantage of being able to close over variables you already have locally.

Comment: So it's not a big benefit to implement this because there would be much more code than before and the logic is only relocated.

Comment: @Piu130 Depends. Breaking it out provides more flexibility and allows stronger testing in isolation, and requires an integration test to make sure the right class or object is accessed. Not sure I'd agree with *much* more code-or if more code is necessarily bad.